# Ionic native component vs Angular custom component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, components, ionic3

I have created angular progress bar component using [**this article**](https://www.joshmorony.com/build-a-simple-progress-bar-component-in-ionic-2/).It's working fine.Can you tell me what is the difference between angular custom component and native [**ionic component like**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#range) `ion-range`?

***Custom angular component:***

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'progress-bar',
  templateUrl: 'progress-bar.html'
})
export class ProgressBarComponent {

  @Input('progress') progress;

  constructor() {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is nothing really. 
Ionic is built on top of angular. All the specific ionic components are built using angular component decorator. A component like [`ion-range`](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/components/range/range.ts) is in fact an Angular component that is within the `ionic-angular` module.

If you check the source linked, it reads as:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ion-range',
  template: '<!-- custom html here -->'

  providers: [ { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: Range, multi: true } ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class Range extends BaseInput<any> implements AfterContentInit, ControlValueAccessor, OnDestroy {
//..
}
```

The input properties of each of the ionic component is defined using angular's `@input()` and all of the output events like `ionChange` are defined using Angular's `EventEmitter`.

Comment: OK.Is that mean, the Angular custom component will support all the platforms (`android, ios and wp`) like Ionic native components?

Comment: that is more to do with the scss defined and which of it gets picked up during the build process..

Comment: there is specific style like .md,.ios and .wp.. you just have to spend some time with the source :) . https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/tree/master/src/components/range

Comment: look at the scss files

Comment: Yep, Got it.Do you think we also need to add such `scss` files for each platform when we develop Angular components or it just works fine without any major issues on all the platforms?

Comment: I guess you will have to go through the build scripts and check how it picks up..you just have to add it within individual scope of `ios`,`md` and `wp`..like any page you create in ionic

Comment: You mean, inside the component's `scss` file?

Comment: Got it.Thank you so much :)